# Making a parameter in a StatefulWidget optional in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a parameter in my StatefulWidget class optional.

Here is the declaration of the class:

```
class TransactionDetailScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'transaction_detail_screen';
  final bool newTrxn;

  const TransactionDetailScreen({this.newTrxn = true, super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<TransactionDetailScreen> createState() =>
      _TransactionDetailScreenState();
}
```

But when I try to call the class without a value for the parameter, I get an error.

Here is where I am trying to call the class without a parameter:

```
final List<Widget> appScreens = [
    const CompanyDashboardScreen(),
    const TransactionDetailScreen(), <<< ERROR HERE
    const AppointmentCalendarScreen(),
    const UserProfileScreen(),
```

Here is the error message:
**A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'bool' in a const constructor.
Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'.dartconst_constructor_param_type_mismatch
TransactionDetailScreen TransactionDetailScreen(
bool bool, {
bool newTrxn = true,
Key? key,
})
];**

How do I make the bool parameter optional?
Thanks

UPDATE:
I have added the ? to the line final bool newTrxn but now I get an new error where I am trying to use the class without a parameter. The error states I need to add the missing argument which is telling me the parameter, newTrxn, is not optional.

Also, I removed the const in front of TransactionDetailScreen() and this is when I get the new argument. If I leave the const I get the same error message as before.

Comment: I think it is not saved properly? In the error message, TransactionDetailScreen( bool bool, { bool newTrxn = true, Key? key, }) has 2 param `bool` and `newTrxn` but in your code you don't have `bool` anymore. Not sure if `bool` is a valid variable name.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I only want to have one parameter in the class, newTrxn which is a bool.

Comment: Just add `?` in the variable, because the error says that it cannot be null, that is, the variable is not nullable, so make it nullable Ex:  `final bool? newTrxn;`

Comment: I did as you suggested but the parameter, newTrxn, is not optional. I added more explanation to the original post.